# Correct NMT metrics with Fairseq on non-latin languages

Tags: python, bleu, fairseq, nmt

As you may know to calculate BLEU properly, you need to pass a tokenizer to it's parameters, in my example I'm working with Korean language, so I expect to pass `--tokenize ko-meca` to sacrebleu.
I know that fairseq calculates bleu for translation task during validation steps, but I found no way to pass that option inside (and even opened an issue https://github.com/facebookresearch/fairseq/issues/5308).

Another option I considered was using cHRF since it's not dependant on tokenization, but as it seems form the code fairseq only uses `bleu` metric from sacrebleu.

I'm also aware that there's an option to compute bleu with your own tokenizer, but in that case the metric becomes tokenizer dependant, which I also don't want.

I would be grateful for any kind of suggestions on the matter.